# Enabling visual styles in visual c++ 64bit dll not working

Tags: c++

I have an Excel .xll addin which loads more dlls. Each dll with user interface has the following pragma enabled:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

It seems to work in 32bit version. Now I have converted the application into 64bit but visual styles do not seem to work unless I add the manifest dependency section in excel.exe.manifest which is not practical when deploying to different machines.

Any ideas pointing to the problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Manifests are loaded with the host application, there's no way around it.

If you want the visual style loaded for your application which is loaded as a library under the host application which doesn't have this property set, one way to do it is to write both the addin and an external executable that has the correct styles, then use IPC (mail slots, UDP, etc) to communicate data between them as needed.